# Angularjs ng-repeat $last is null in IE 7.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm using ng-repeat in IE 7.0. I'm not sure why but I'm getting an error that $last is undefined. I'm happy to handle this for IE 7.0 but when I try various expressions I get errors.

I was hoping that someone had a work around that they could recommend? I've tried filter:{$last:null}:false

```
<span data-ng-repeat="group in groups" class="funnel-cells {{ filter:{$last:null}:false && 'funnel-cells-last' }}">
```

Comment: IE 7 is not really supported http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie  Even Microsoft support states they have 5-10 year support on the products which means IE 8 should be beyond the 5 years in 2014 (being released in 2009), IE 7 was released in 2006.

Comment: hey thanks for the history lesson. In some cases older browsers need to be supported, each project is different. Our Angular app works fine in IE 7 > besides the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

This will result in slightly decreased performance across browsers, but if IE7 is a requirement, you could try:

In your controller:

```
$scope.isLastGroup = function(group) {
    return $scope.groups[$scope.groups.length-1] == group;
};
```

And in your template:

```
<span ... ng-class="{'funnel-cells-last': isLastGroup(group)}">
```

Comment: The @colllin I'll give it a try.

Comment: I opted to have a conditional comment inside the hTML that hides the repeater functionality. I was not ready to have the performance hit, especially since IE7 has enough issues already. thanks again for helping me.